# Xcode: iPad iOS 3.2.2 debugging problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

I am trying to provision my app to run on my iPad for testing.  I have everything set up properly, but in the organizer, Xcode displays this message:

```
The version of iPhone OS on “iPad” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS 
supported for development with this installation of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the 
device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iPhone SDK;
```

and then it gives me a list of available iOS versions (3.2.2 is not one of them.)

I have restored it back to the factory settings and done everything I could find online and searched around.  Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?  It won't let me compile it to the device as a result.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the iOS SDK are you using? Make sure you're using the most recent.

Comment: It's Xcode 3.2.3  I am going to update the most recent version off the site (3.2.4?)  I'll let you know if that was the problem.

Comment: The version of Xcode doesn't matter as much as the SDK version does. As of today (9/23/2010), the SDK version on Apple's site is 4.1. You'll have to verify that iOS 3.2.2 is supported by that SDK.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!